# Remove space between frames?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently trying to set up a tkinter program in which I have 2 frames. 1 contains 2 entry fields and a button. The second frame contains a text field. I have made configurations so that the text field and the entry fields resize to my desired specifications (for example, text field fills it's whole frame). When I resize the window though, I have come to find that there is an empty space between these two frames that stretches vertically as I stretch the window vertically. I have tried to remedy this in a number of different ways but nothing seems to work.

How do I know the space is between the frames?
Well, when I placed borders around the frames the space is between the two borders, aka, outside of either frames.

I use .pack() method on the two frames if this helps.

Is there any way of removing this empty space between frames? Thanks.

```
import os
from os import path
from os import listdir
from tkinter import *



class OrdIFiler:
    def __init__(self):
        

        self.found_term = {}
        self.files_searched = 0
        self.dir_searched = 0
        self.lines_found = 0

        window = Tk()
        window.title("Finn ord i filer")
        window.geometry("1000x400")
        
        frame1 = Frame(window,highlightbackground="blue", highlightthickness=2, height=30)
        frame1.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        frame1.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        frame1.pack(expand=True, fill='x', anchor='n')
        frame1.pack_propagate(False)
        frame1.grid_propagate(False)
        
        self.file_dir_name = StringVar()
        file_entry = Entry(frame1, fg="gray", textvariable=self.file_dir_name, width=100)
        file_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        file_entry.insert(0, "Directory or file path")
        file_entry.bind('<FocusIn>', self.clear_default)

        self.search_term = StringVar()
        term_entry = Entry(frame1, text="Search term", fg="gray", textvariable=self.search_term)
        term_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, stick="we")
        term_entry.insert(0, "Search term")
        term_entry.bind('<FocusIn>', self.clear_default)

        btn_search = Button(frame1, text="Search", command = self.searching).grid(row=0,column=2, sticky="e")

        frame2 = Frame(window, highlightbackground="red", highlightthickness=2)
        frame2.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        frame2.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        frame2.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        self.text_field = Text(frame2)
        self.text_field.grid(sticky="nsew")
        self.text_field.insert(END, " ")


        window.mainloop()


    def clear_default(self, event):
        event.widget.delete(0,END)
        event.widget.config(fg="black")
        #event.widget.unbind('<FocusIn>')


    def searching(self):
        self.files_searched = 0
        self.dir_searched = 0

        self.text_field.delete("0.0",END)
        self.text_field.insert(END, "Search start\n--------------------------\n")

        self.recursive_search(self.file_dir_name.get(), self.search_term.get())

        search_term = self.search_term.get()

        self.text_field.insert(END, "--------------------------\nSearch Ended\n")
        self.text_field.insert(END, f"Searched: {self.dir_searched:4} directories and {self.files_searched:5} files. {self.lines_found}")
        self.text_field.insert(END, f" occurances " if self.lines_found>1 else " occurance ") 
        self.text_field.insert(END, f"of '{search_term}'")

        print(self.found_term)



    def recursive_search(self, file_dir_name, search_term):
        
        if path.isfile(file_dir_name):
            self.files_searched += 1
            text = open(file_dir_name, "r")
            try:
                for line in text:
                    if search_term in line:
                        self.lines_found += 1
                        self.text_field.insert(END,f'{file_dir_name:70}{line}')
                        if file_dir_name in self.found_term.keys():
                            self.found_term[file_dir_name].append(line.strip("\n"))
                        else:
                            self.found_term[file_dir_name] = [line.strip("\n")]

            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                print(text, "could not be read due to unicode-8 codec format error\n")
            text.close()

        elif path.isdir(file_dir_name):
            self.dir_searched += 1
            for x in listdir(file_dir_name):
                self.recursive_search(file_dir_name+"/"+x, search_term)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can't diagnose code that we can't see.

Comment: Appologies, that was dumb, I wasn't thinking straight, the code is there now. It's messy and probably has a bit of useless code in it but It's the result of repeated tries to fix this.

Comment: Since the question is about what the UI looks like, we don't need some of the functions like `recursive_search` and `searching`.

Comment: I thought i would leave in the methods incase anyone wanted to run the code to see the issue for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You have set `expand` to true for both frames. That means that any extra space when resizing the window will be allocated to both frames.

The solution to your specific problem is to leave the default value of `expand`, or set it to `False`, for `frame1`.

```
frame1.pack(expand=False, fill='x', anchor='n')
```

Comment: Beautiful, that fixed it. I thought expand would only effect what was within the frame. I need to reread what effect expanse has. Thank you!